# How to Nest VLOOKUP properly in Nested IF statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I swear I am not being lazy. After staying up late one night I figured out how to make all this work. But of course I did not save, and the computer froze before I got back to it.

Drop Box Link at the bottom of this post

This workbook helps therapists:

Record sensitive personal information about clients individually on community specific sheets (E.g. WLFN and CLCN are specific communities)
Create a value only copy of To Export to be submitted weekly
The **Template Interface** sheet is for therapists to enter their weekly data.

[Templates Interface Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B37lS.png)

**Column A** ='Data Entry'!$C$4:$C$12

**Column B** ='Data Entry'!$F$4:$F$54

**Column C** =A3&B3

E & F are failing.  E results in FALSE. F results in #N/A
**Column E** =IF(A3="FDFN",VLOOKUP(C3, FDFN!A4:J49, 2, IF(A3="WLFN",VLOOKUP(C3, WLFN!A4:J49, 2, IF(A3="CLCN",VLOOKUP(C3, CLCN!A4:J49, 2, IF(A3="ERFN",VLOOKUP(C3, ERFN!A4:J49, 2, FALSE))))))))

**Column F** =IF(A3="FDFN",VLOOKUP(C3, FDFN!A4:J49, 2, IF(A3="WLFN",VLOOKUP(C3, WLFN!A4:J49, 2, IF(A3="CLCN",VLOOKUP(C3, CLCN!A4:J49, 2, IF(A3="ERFN",VLOOKUP(C3, ERFN!A4:J49, 2, FALSE))))))))

Below is a sample of an individual community sheet called **WLFN**.

[Sample of Community Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwXKf.png)

I would like to fix the errors.

Also would like to know if there is a better way of Shorlisting the Client Reference based on the data validation in **Column A**. Right now I am simply combining A & B to get C, using &. (=A3&B3)

Drop Box Link > https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1z1fd31m265egh/Example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Someone solved it!!!

In cell E3, enter this formula

=VLOOKUP(A3&"~"&B3,INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!B4:J49"),2,0)

In cell G3, enter this formula

=VLOOKUP(A3&"~"&B3,INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!B4:J49"),5,0)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Ashish Mathur
www.ashishmathur.com
http://twitter.com/excelashish

Comment: You may use in this pattern also,, `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D95,A95:B98,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D95,A99:B101,2,0),VLOOKUP(D95,A103:B105,2,0)))' where The `IFERROR` function is designed to trap errors and perform an alternate action.

Comment: Your formula should written like this,, `=IF(D95="A",VLOOKUP(D96, A95:B97, 2,FALSE), IF(D95="B",VLOOKUP(D96, A99:B101, 2,FALSE), IF(D95="C",VLOOKUP(D96, A103:B105, 2,  FALSE),"")))` Where `A, B  & C` are `3` groups in `D95` has related Lookup in `D96` for respective Ranges.

Answer (score 0):

In cell E3, enter this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A3&"~"&B3,INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!B4:J49"),2,0)
```

In cell G3, enter this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A3&"~"&B3,INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!B4:J49"),5,0)
```

Hope this help.

Courtesy, Ashish Mathur
www.ashishmathur.com
http://twitter.com/excelashish

Answer (score 0):

To be clear about the reason for earlier failure, it is the existence of the tilde (`~`) character in the second column with it being "escaped."

Excel has a few "special characters" that are used to mean something extra when used, as in they are considered to convey the "special meaning" rather than their literal character value when used by themselves.

`~` is used to convey that the character following it is to be used as its literal self. In other words, it has no meaning as itself, it is just the indicator (the "escape character") that the following character should not be interpreted as having the special meaning that Excel uses it for.

An example is the `*` character. Ordinary use of it causes Excel to treat it as the "anything" wildcard character. To, let's say, search for a `*` character one would search using this string:  `~*`.

So, `VLOOKUP()` reads the value in that column B ("Numerical" column) cell, it reads the `~` as saying "consider the next character, "0", as its literal self, not its special self. No matter than "0" is not any kind of special character... the programming in Excel is not quite that "sophisticated." It simply ignores the `~` as a character itself and uses that "0" as a "0". So the string it reads from the cell is NOT `~00001` but rather `00001` and, well, that is simply not there to be found.

The reason then, that the solution's formula works is that another `~` is added into the string so that what exists is now `~~00001" which Excel processes by dropping the first` ~`and knowing to interpret the next one, the one part of the cell's contents, as literally a`~`, not as a special character.

So now the search string is exactly what is in the cell and the lookup succeeds.